# Magento2: How to remove extra white background from uploaded image from admin

Tags: image-upload, magento-2.1.3

Extra white background appears when the image uploaded is not the same dimension where it is requested.

I used resize code for image resizing:

```
if (!file_exists($imageResized)) { $imageResize = $this->_imageFactory->create(); $imageResize->open($absolutePath); $imageResize->constrainOnly(true); $imageResize->keepTransparency(true); $imageResize->keepFrame(true); $imageResize->keepAspectRatio(false); $imageResize->resize($width, $height); $destination = $imageResized; $imageResize->save($destination); }
```

For example, the image uploaded is 200x200 and it is called somewhere at a proportion of 300x200. So the image will resize to fit for the position without being stretched out rather resizing it to the proportion with extra white space. so How remove white background?
[image]

Comment: R u using any custom module for image resize or u have code? If have code then paste it

Comment: yes..i have resize code.

Comment: if (!file_exists($imageResized)) {
    
                $imageResize = $this->_imageFactory->create();
                $imageResize->open($absolutePath);
                $imageResize->constrainOnly(true);
                $imageResize->keepTransparency(true);
                $imageResize->keepFrame(true);
                $imageResize->keepAspectRatio(false);
                $imageResize->resize($width, $height);
                $destination = $imageResized;
                $imageResize->save($destination);
            }

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your line,

`$imageResize->keepFrame(true)`

with

```
$imageResize->keepFrame(false)
```

This is my block file,

```
class YOURCLASS extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
     protected $_productloader;
     protected $productimghelper;

     public function __construct(Context $context, 
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productloader,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $producthelper)
    {

        $this->_productloader = $productloader;
        $this->productimghelper = $producthelper;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function ProductImageData($Pid)
    {
        $product = $this->_productloader->load($Pid); 
        $imgURL = $this->productimghelper->init($product, 'category_page_list')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(FALSE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(300,200)->getUrl();
    }
}
```

In my phtml file, I put code like this,

```
<img src="<?php echo $block->ProductImageData(123);?>"/>
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer but its not working..,

Comment: you are trying to save new image in place of old image with your code?

Comment: yes..i have save new image.

Comment: you need to used above code to show images, and apply above things there.

Comment: I have used above code but not working..if you have code can you paste here?

Comment: I updated answer, please check.

Comment: Thanx but this code working product image.but not custom resize function in. my resize method like that..if (!file_exists($imageResized)) { $imageResize = $this->_imageFactory->create(); $imageResize->open($absolutePath); $imageResize->constrainOnly(true); $imageResize->keepTransparency(false); $imageResize->keepFrame(false); $imageResize->keepAspectRatio(false); $imageResize->resize($width, $height); $destination = $imageResized; $imageResize->save($destination); }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51693/discussion-between-dhiren-vasoya-and-magento2-devloper).